# Cannot instantiate the type error for in app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement the inapp billing feature and I have the following in my main activity:

```
public class screen_Home extends base_Activity{
...
private AppPurchaseObserver appPurchaseObserver;
private Handler handler;
...
private abstract class AppPurchaseObserver extends PurchaseObserver {
    public AppPurchaseObserver(Handler handler) {
         super(BT_screen_home.this, handler);
    }
}
...
```

And in in the onCreate:

```
...
handler = new Handler();         
appPurchaseObserver = new AppPurchaseObserver(handler); 
....
```

On this last line, AppPurchaseObserver is underlined in red in Eclipse giving the error : cannot instantiate the type screen_Home.AppPurchaseObserver

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for your help

Comment: well, it is abstract. it cannot be instanciated. that's what is does.

Comment: Thanks, I am not experienced in java, what should I do to fix this error ?

Comment: don't make abstract classes you want to instanciate ?

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes can't be instantiated. You can read more about abstract classes in Java **[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)**. Take out the `abstract` identifier and you can instantiate `AppPurchaseObserver`

Answer (score 0):

Try `import android.os.Handler;`

instead of `import java.util.logging.Handler;`